# There is no parent and before sibling css selector so what I'm supposed to do?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have situation like that

```
<section>

    <div>On a hover change css here</div>

    <a>Hover me</a>

</section>
```

I want to `change css of div when a is hovered`.

**Div have to be before a** and there is no selector to select sibling that is before element.([related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector))

I also tried do do something like `section:has(> a) >img` but :has() selector has very weak [browsers support](https://caniuse.com/css-has). ([related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector))

Is there any way to do this thing in only css or using simple js?

(Stack is telling me that this question has been answered in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) so here is the difference: In [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) the question is about existance of previous sibling selector and the answers aren't much helpful in this situation and in my question I ask about how to do this in this specific situation)

Comment: Sibling selectors only work for *subsequent* siblings, so there is no CSS solution for this. You need to use Javascript/jQuery

Comment: No, there is nothing in css to do that. you need to use some JS code

Comment: Ok, but how to do it in the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript is pretty straightforward. Give the anchor you want an id (I've called it 'hoverme')

```
<section>
  <div>On a hover change css here</div>
  <a id="hoverme">Hover me</a>
</section>
```

Add a class to cover styling the div (e.g. this)

```
<style>
  .hoverdiv {
    color:red;
  }
</style>
```

Then just add a couple of event listeners to the anchor at the window.onload event like this:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    const anchor=document.querySelector('#hoverme');
    anchor.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
      event.target.parentElement.querySelector('div').classList.add('hoverdiv');
    });
    anchor.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
      event.target.parentElement.querySelector('div').classList.remove('hoverdiv');
    });
  });
</script>
```